# How can I make a protein interaction/protein-complex network?

Tags: bioinformatics, homework, database

Let's say I have a list of proteins ID. I would like to know whether I can find any complex based on that list. Any example, explanation is appreciated.

An example input is what you see below. What can I do with the following list of protein IDs? These IDs are from human.

```
P41182,P56524, P41182,Q9UQL6, P41182,Q8WUI4,Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9,Q92831
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "complex"? Do you want to know if they are part of an oligomeric quaternary structure, or how they interact with other proteins?

Comment: @James if they are part of oligomeric quaternary structure

Comment: This question is not a homework question. It is not a trivial, easily google-able task. I buy the "too-broad" argument, but closing this for homework seems a bit naive. Even if it's an assignment it's a tough one if you don't know where to start!

Comment: Without a pairwise mapping between interacting proteins, you cannot make the network. Do you have a file that contains this information?

Comment: @WYSIWYG No I don't have such info, do you know how to get that ? please make another answer if you know a better way

Comment: @Mol you need to somehow know which proteins interact with which others. This can be experimentally found out using techniques such as Co-IP (it can also show indirect interactions though). Whatever techniques or predictions you use, you would need to know the individual edges of the network to actually build it. Otherwise, it is impossible.

Comment: @WYSIWYG If I know that these proteins are coming from the same sample, then I can assume they interact , no ?

Comment: @Mol no you cannot assume so. In a protein extract from a eukaryotic cell actin and cyclin would both be present but they do not interact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a trivial task depending on how well studied your network is or what information you want to gather. It sounds like an interaction dataset is what you want rather than scouring the PDB for static structures (that would be such a hit and miss process I'm not sure it's worth bothering).

1. Upload you list of gene codes to [string-db](http://string-db.org/).

   - You'll see the network here, and structures are made clear of known complexes in an expandable thumbnail.
   - It's a limited web-server tool, and whilst very powerful, isn't very flexible. Cytoscape might be needed for a more novel study because it is scriptable.

   **You can probably stop here and investigate your network.**
2. From string-db download the `.txt` file (TXT - simple tab delimited flatfile). I think it's an old-school save icon on the web-server, although if you're uploading multiple identifiers, it is simply the "save" button at the top left.
3. Download [Cytoscape here.](http://www.cytoscape.org/)
4. Then use `File`>`Import`>`Table`>`From file`.
5. This will build an interaction network and you'll see which genes/proteins interact with one another.

Catch: whilst this provides spacial information, you can't get a picture of temporal information: *i.e* you know what is interacting, but not when nor for how long.

Comment: how to get the .SIF ? how to give all the ID together ? i tried to save it but it did not give me any .SIF

Comment: Did you manage to get string-db to display an interaction network?

Comment: not for all IDs together but when I use one ID, it works

Comment: Have you tried uploading them all at once under the [multiple identifiers tab](http://string-db.org/newstring_cgi/show_input_page.pl?UserId=btR3QmOuPgWH&sessionId=bUsiKWwohNKl&input_page_type=multiple_identifiers)?

Comment: both txt files are the same ?  also can you please give me some hint related to the CytoScape? what to study and where to study so that I can get an idea how to build the network and visualise it

Comment: @Mol if cytoscape is a bit overkill then just stick to string-db. All the nodes and connection show interacting partners.

Comment: I know but seems more flexible than String-db. both txt are similar ?

Comment: @Mol The tab delimited txt file is the one you want. Cytoscape is more flexible you're right. *But* that flexibility comes at a cost; a steep learning curve. There may even be a way to query from within Cytoscape. What I like about string-db is the direct links to pdb structures which is probably very useful for you.